# how to iterate over flatmap in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to run a flatMap inside a for loop in spark like that:

```
def clusterVar(points: DStream[ArrayBuffer[Double]]): DStream[ArrayBuffer[Double]]={
var best = new ArrayBuffer[Double]()
var bestVarianceSum = Double.PositiveInfinity
for (i <- 0 until numTrials) { 
    val clusters = cluster(points)
    // compute the variance of the current list
    clusters.flatMap(cl => {
      val varianceSum = score(cl)
      if (varianceSum < bestVarianceSum) { 
        best.appendAll(cl)
        bestVarianceSum = varianceSum
      }
      best
    })
  }
//return value: clusters:DStream[ArrayBuffer[Double]]
}
```

but I don't know how to return the cluster dstream since it's created inside the for loop. Any thoughts how to do this?

Comment: what's the type signature of `cluster` ?

Comment: it's DStream[ArrayBuffer[Double]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to fetch the data from the `for` loop, need to use `yield`. Here is the sample code.

```
object SOF {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val x = for (i <- 1 to 5) yield i
        x.foreach(println)
    }
}
```

Output: 12345

Here variable `x` becomes of type `IndexedSeq[Int]`. In your case, for getting variable `clusters`, you need to keep your loop something like this.

```
val final_data = for (i <- 0 until numTrials) yield { 
    val clusters = cluster(points)
    // compute the variance of the current list
    clusters.flatMap(cl => {
      val varianceSum = score(cl)
      if (varianceSum < bestVarianceSum) { 
        best.appendAll(cl)
        bestVarianceSum = varianceSum
      }
      best
    })
  }
clusters
 }
```

Variable `final_data` becomes of type `IndexedSed[T]`. `T` is of your variable `clusters` type.